Sqlite3 Checking to see if a record exists
I have scoured stackoverflow for answers and none that i found have worked for me.
I want to check if a user already exists in an sqlite3 database
self.c.execute('SELECT username AND password, COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE username=? AND password=? GROUP BY username',(self.reg_username_entry.get(), self.reg_password_entry.get()))
self.c.fetchall()
self.row_count = self.c.rowcount
if self.row_count == 1:
    self.my_label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(self.reg_window, text = 'User already exists', font=('Arial', 10)).pack(pady=10)
else:
    self.c.execute('INSERT INTO users (username, password) VALUES(?, ?)', (self.reg_username_entry.get(), self.reg_password_entry.get()))
    self.conn.commit()
    self.Login()

I tried this code. I know it worked for on other database modules, but apparently not on sqlite3 because fetchall() returns a tuple of tuples in sqlite3.
This code does nothing when i type in a user that i know already exists. But it is successful at writing new users to the database if they do not exist.

When you're selecting multiple columns, you separate them with ,, not AND. username AND password should be username, password

Why are you using COUNT(*)? Can there really be more than one user with the same username?

Why do you need to select the password?

Don't select COUNT(*). This will always return a single row, even if the user is not found -- the count will be 0.
Just select a single column, and check the row count.
self.c.execute('SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE username=? AND password=?',(self.reg_username_entry.get(), self.reg_password_entry.get()))
self.row_count = self.c.rowcount
if self.row_count == 1:
    self.my_label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(self.reg_window, text = 'User already exists', font=('Arial', 10)).pack(pady=10)
else:
    self.c.execute('INSERT INTO users (username, password) VALUES(?, ?)', (self.reg_username_entry.get(), self.reg_password_entry.get()))
    self.conn.commit()
    self.Login()

BTW, you shouldn't store plaintext passwords. Passwords should be hashed, and you should compare the hash of the given password with the hashed password; see Salt and hash a password in Python. Your best bet would be to use an authentication framework from a library rather than implementing this yourself.

Hi there. This method does not work

I forgot to remove the GROUP BY username part of the query.

I will try that thank you.
